# Putting A Specific Row From Linq Result On Top?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Let's say I have a linq query like the one below

```
var LinqResult =
    from a in Db.Table
    select new {Table = a};
```

From here, how can I grab a specific row from these results and put it on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 orderby (a.Id == someId ? 1 : 2)
```

That make the ordering rather explicit, by sorting on the numbers 1 or 2, depending on whether or not it's the desired top value.

You could simplify that a bit, by sorting on the bool expression itself, except `false < true`,  so to get someId on top, you must either write:

```
 orderby a.Id != someId
```

or

```
 orderby a.Id == someId descending
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 orderby a.Id == someId // or some other condition
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which row you want on top based on say an id, you could try ordering based on that rows id.

```
var LinqResult =
    from a in Db.Table
    orderby a.Id == checkId descending
    select new {Table = a};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var LinqResult =
    (from a in Db.Table
    select new {a.column}).Orderby();
```